# imageresizer sqlreader no longer supports stored procedures?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, imageresizer

I've been using imageresizer and the sqlreader plugin for a few years now without issues.  I just upgraded from version 3.4.3 to version 4.0.4 and now the sqlreader plugin doesn't seem to work.  I have a gist here:
https://gist.github.com/vishnu4/a859c2599f46998b612a
the main thing that i can see is that i used stored procedures for my SQL calls, which you used to support using the 'queriesAreStoredProcedures' parameter.  Looking at your documentation on http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/sqlreader , that parameter doesn't seem to exist anymore.   Is there another way to support this functionality, or did it disappear?

Edit:  The error i get in the browser console is:

> [SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.]
>      System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBytes.get_Length() +2960929
>      ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.GetStreamFromSource(Object source, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean& disposeStream, String& path, Boolean& restoreStreamPosition) +1156
>      ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.LoadImage(Object source, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean restoreStreamPos) +555
>      ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.BuildJob(ImageJob job) +243
>      ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(ImageJob job) +317
>      ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean disposeSource, Boolean addFileExtension) +177
>      ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean disposeSource) +36
>      ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings) +25
>      ImageResizer.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<HandleRequest>b__1(Stream stream) +171
>      ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<TryWriteFile>b__0() +496
>      ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.LockProvider.TryExecute(String key, Int32 timeoutMs, LockCallback success) +409
>      ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.CustomDiskCache.GetCachedFile(String keyBasis, String extension, ResizeImageDelegate writeCallback, Int32 timeoutMs, Boolean asynchronous) +545
>      ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache.Process(IResponseArgs e) +125
>      ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache.Process(HttpContext context, IResponseArgs e) +60
>      ImageResizer.InterceptModule.CheckRequest_PostAuthorizeRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +449
>      System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +142
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `queriesAreStoredProcedures` configuration parameter is fully supported in V4, although the docs fail to mention it.

Please be more specific about what does not work, and the specific error message and stack trace you receive.

**Update**

Looking at the error message, it appears that the row you're querying has a null value for the row that is returned. It is strange that an exception is thrown, considering [the docs for SqlBytes.Length indicate it should return -1 instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbytes.length(v=vs.100).aspx).

I suggest using Sql Server Profiler or IntelliTrace to see the exact SQL command your configuration has generated, and verifying that the first column of the first result, in fact, contains image bytes.

Comment: please see the above edit for the console error.  The image just doesn't show, it shows in the browser as a broken image.  The site worked fine, i updated imageresizer via nuget to v4, and now i get this error without change anything else in my code

Comment: that image is blank, which is why i have the Image404 plugin as well.  You're right, if i use a link that actually does have an image, it works, but for the ones that don't have an image, they ignore my '&404=...' query string parameter.  Has the use of this changed?

Comment: The 404 behavior can be fixed by [adding another conditional](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/imazen/resizer/branch/develop/job/lh0yd9gjpqx60bab).

Comment: Sorry, but what should i change?  Your link just goes to a build log

Comment: Click the "artifacts" tab to access a .zip file of the build results. These should have the hotfix applied.